# c++: Function using method of object defined in main

Tags: c++, function, oop, object, methods

Good Morning.
Me and my team are facing a problem with our c++ assignment.
In main we are defining two instances of a class called Team, "Team famous, Team fighters". Inside main we are calling a function called "team details"; inside that function we are trying to access public methods of the instances we just created(famous.getName). The following message appears:

error: request for member 'getName' in 'famous', which is of non-class type 'teamdetails() ::team_t'

The message concerns the calls made inside that switch loop you can see in the code below. We can't find out where the problem comes from.
*Is it a problem that 'famous.getName' is used in a function in which object 'famous' was not declered in? *
NOTE: function 'teamdetails()' is called by function 'menu()', which is called by main.

Thank you for your help!

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Team.h"
using namespace std;

void teamdetails();

int main(){
   Team famous;
   Team fighters;
   cout<<"Welcome to the \"Survivor Experience of a lifetime\" !!!"<<endl;
   menu();
return 0;)

void teamdetails(){
   cout << " Which team are you interested in ? <famous/fighters>\t";
   enum team_t {famous = 0, fighters = 1};
   team_t   team_as_enum;  
   // cin >> team_as_enum;      // -> does not work.    Below I am trying
   //another alternative.

   string team;
   cin >>team;
   for(;;)
       if((team == "famous") || (team == "fighters"))
          break;

   if (team == "famous")
      team_as_enum = famous;
   else if(team == "fighters")
      team_as_enum = fighters;
   else
      cout<<"sth went wrong with your input";


   switch (team_as_enum){
      case famous: 
        cout<<"The name is"<< famous.getName() <<endl;
        cout<<"The number of players is "<<famous.getPlayers()<<endl;
        cout<<"Portions are "<<famous.getPortions()<<endl;
        cout<<"Victory : "<<famous.getVictories()<<endl;
        break;

      case fighters:  
        cout<<"The name is"<<fighters.getName()<<endl;
        cout<<"The number of players is "<<fighters.getPlayers()<<endl;
        cout<<"Portions are "<<fighters.getPortions()<<endl;
        cout<<"Victory : "<<fighters.getVictories()<<endl;
        break;
      default:
        cout<<"Ooop Entry not correct . Next time enter one of the following
        team's name <famous/fighters>"<<endl;
    }

    }
```

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: Typo at end of main: `;)`.  This is usually used indicate how a statement should be interpreted, in comments or social media.

Comment: You have a nasty infinite loop.  Type "gold" as your input to see what happens.  There is no input from the user if the comparisons fail, so the loop executes forever.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to singly execute each statement and *watch* the values in variables.  A lot faster than posting to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to debug your program for you.

Comment: Why are you converting to `enum`?  The `switch` has only two cases, so you *could* use the string comparison and remove the `switch`.

Comment: BTW, functions cannot access variables inside other functions.  The variables in `main` are not available to `teamdetails`.  Prefer to pass the variables by reference to the `teamdetails` function.

Answer (score 0):

You reuse `famous` variable name inside of your `teamdetails` function by declaring `enum team_t {famous = 0, fighters = 1};`. Chose a different name. And variable `famous` of type `Team` is not visible inside of that function at all as it is declared inside of `main` function scope, you need to pass it to `teamdetails` as argument.